# Flutter: How to Pop back just after route stack is empty?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

So, here is what I am trying to do. I am clicking on a button (from a popup alert) to delete a particular firebase record then navigating back until route.isFirst and then one more step back because I don't want to stay on a page that is deleted in database.
Here is my code (not working)

```
TextButton(
              child: Text(
                "Delete",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("board")
                    .doc(selectedDocumentId)
                    .collection(selectedDocumentId)
                    .get()
                    .then((snapshot) {
                      for (DocumentSnapshot doc in snapshot.docs) {
                        doc.reference.delete();
                      }
                    })
                    .then((value) async {
                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("board")
                          .doc(selectedDocumentId)
                          .delete();
                    })
                    .**then((value) =>
                        Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst))
                    .then((value) =>
                        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop());
              }),**
```

Comment: when `route.isFirst` is true, it should be literally the first page of the app. Are you sure you are deleting this page from the route stack?

Comment: My Navigation is like this - Home Page -> Page A -> Delete Popup -> Delete action. On this action I am landing on Page A (which contain deleted data). But I want to land to Home page. That is why I am popping once more time. Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to return to a specific page, deleting all pages in the stack:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => name_of_home_page()),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```

If you want to restart the application instead (because maybe you have changed some parameters or something else), you can use Phoenix (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phoenix)

Answer (score 0):

Since the delete is awaited the next call to navigator can be executed after that without adding a then. Also if you navigate to the first route you must have already reached the first page of the app where there is no more page to pop.

```dart
onPressed: () async {
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("board")
                    .doc(selectedDocumentId)
                    .collection(selectedDocumentId)
                    .get()
                    .then((snapshot) {
                      for (DocumentSnapshot doc in snapshot.docs) {
                        doc.reference.delete();
                      }
                    })
                    .then((value) async {
                      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("board")
                          .doc(selectedDocumentId)
                          .delete();
 Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst));
})
              }),
```

Comment: I tried this code and navigation is like this - Home Page -> Page A -> Delete Popup alert -> Delete action ->PopUntil Page.isFirst. This still lands me on Page A but I want to move back to Home Page.

Comment: Then you may remove navigator.pop and try. Push and remove until